# offsetHeight vs. clientHeight

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the height of a div using javascript. I have seen this question a lot on stackoverflow and seen both answers. Some say clientHeight and some say offsetHeight. For my project, I have a div with content inside that does not have a pre-set css height. I want to get the height of it with javascript. Which is better to use? and please NO JQUERY. Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as better or worse in this case, you just have to decide what information you need/want. The 2 properties are just different as they provide specific information. offsetHeight gives you the height of the element including vertical padding and borders while clientHeight gives you the inner height of an element, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was asking for @NunoArruda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two is what is included in the value you get.

Specifically, **clientHeight** will give you the height of the visible height of the div including the padding but excluding the scrollBar, border and margin whereas **offsetHeight** will give you the visible height of the div including scrollBar, padding and the border but excluding the margin.

Answer (score 1):

`.Height` if you need height of div excluding margin/padding/border.

`.innerHeight` if you need height of div with padding but without border + margin

`.outerHeight` if you need height of div including padding and border

`.outerHeight(true)` if you need height of div including border + margin + padding